# Accessing an integer dict key within the print function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

This runs ok:

```
x={'1':100,'2':200,'3':300}
print("I scored %(1)s"%x)
```

This doesn't:

```
x={1:100,2:200,3:300}
print("I scored %(1)s"%x)
```

How do I modify the print() statement so that it accesses the dict item with integer key 1 ?

Comment: Note that your problem is not with the `print()` statement (which is really a function, not a statement), but rather with the `%` operator as applied to strings.

Comment: thanks Martijn - wonder what is so wrong with my question - it is clear - it is relatively gerneral - I realise it's very basic but that isn't a criteria for down-voting.

Comment: FWIW, I *upvoted*, because you showed what you tried, and it is clear to me what output you expect. The documentation does mention that mapping key *consist\[s] of a parenthesised sequence of characters*, but that is reasonably obscure enough to find.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks ... any question in connection with `C#` or `Python` get down-voted if they are not advanced enough for the readers taste! The `sql` community is a lot more forgiving and questions don't get down-voted nearly as much.

Comment: Nah, I don't quite agree with that assessment. Don't worry too much about this one. We currently have a persistently grumpy member in the Python community (temp banned before for overly condescending behaviour), you must have caught some people on an overly grumpy time.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. I actually think that the review system needs to be looked at as this happens in other circles of `SO` - I've always assumed this community is not supposed to be exclusive to people who already _know everything_...it would struggle if that was the case.

Comment: I don't think a review queue for downvoted posts is going to happen. You can try and make your case on [Meta], but make sure it wasn't proposed before (search) and do try and make a strong case. Meta voting is based on merit of the idea as well as quality, so be prepared to be downvoted on a proposal if people disagree with the content of the proposal.

Comment: @MartijnPieters like some sort of recursive proposal about down-voting that gets down-voted!

Comment: Something like that.. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203007/downvoting-an-accepted-answer for a recent example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ...ok...think research and evidence is required before you get to laugh at my hugely down-voted proposal..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%(name)x` format *always* uses strings to look up the name in the dictionary.

Use the newer [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead:

```
>>> x={1:100,2:200,3:300}
>>> "I scored {0[1]}".format(x)
'I scored 100'
```

Comment: +1 thanks Martijn - `print("I scored {0[1]}".format(x))` does exactly what I want.